# What is this 'ScaryGen' worldgen option I'm seeing in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I went ahead and installed a small number of mods and <s>then they crashed</s> they're working without issues so far, however I noticed this new World Type option added by one of them upon creating a new world.

[image: World Type: ScaryGen]

Upon clicking the Customization button that comes with it, these are the only UI elements greeting me on the screen.

[image: Default generation values; index: 1, heightLevel: 128, oceanLevel: 63, cloudLevel: 128, geostrataGen: 0, text field with "minecraft:water" and a help icon, Done and Cancel buttons.]

The UI here confuses me to no end. I've got no idea what this is supposed to do, or, for that matter, *which mod added this in the first place*.

**What mod has the ScaryGen world type option, and how do I use it?**

---

***Update:***

[image: I, uh... the map is just about at cloud level right now.]

*uhm.* Looks like I enabled it by accident with the default values.
Now I'm even more confused.

Comment: Google returned this https://github.com/da3dsoul/Additional-Buildcraft-Objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would probably be [Additional Buildcraft Objects](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/2310397-additional-buildcraft-objects-a-plugin-for)

I can't find any documentation referencing it, but the [repository for the mod references it](https://github.com/da3dsoul/Additional-Buildcraft-Objects/blob/cc5a9f4b83b8cc4c4a0a3957c526d3ce55c9164b/src/main/java/da3dsoul/scaryGen/generate/WorldTypeScary.java), as well as the forum post. It seems to be a bit of a hidden feature.

I have no idea what the index option does, but the *Level things seem to be the height to generate it at. geostrataGen is for supporting a mod called [GeoStrata](https://sites.google.com/site/reikasminecraft/geostrata).

The input field is what to replace the water with, can be any block as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is from ABO, to answer a couple of quick things
index 0= normal world gen
index 1= Super flat with cool ravines
index 2= One with bigger ravines and less flat areas
index 3= Lots of tiny chunks ripped up out of the ground
index 4= Normal with pointer mountains and cooler biomes in general
index 5= 3 with BIGGER chunks ripped out of the ground
index 6= 4 but smoother

The text box is indeed for replacing the water of oceans, do note oceans have random rivers in them and this will lead to weird formations depending on what it's replaced with.  Also if you replace water with something like lava it will stress the client due to the lighting changes and updates, on top of the constantly changing state.  Similar blocks will cause the same problems.  (Energized glow stone is bad, don't do it, or do it and plan to delete that world, I recommend scary gen 5 to test this)

The dev is one of my best friends so I've a lot of time playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the chunk generator code, the index appears to be a value which controls scary noises on worldgen. It appears to make different noises on values of 0-6 than it does for any other number.

here is a pastebin link with the snippets
http://pastebin.com/YNqnuZRY
this is a lines 503-515 and 603-630 from a file in the source code on github for this mod
https://github.com/da3dsoul/Additional-Buildcraft-Objects/blob/MC1.7.10--BC7.1%2B/src/main/java/da3dsoul/scaryGen/generate/ChunkProviderScary.java

Comment: Would be great if you showed a snippet of code from the source that proved this.

Comment: sure, i have a pastebin. You can find it in the github, it is in src/main/java/da3dsoul/scaryGen/generate/ChunkProviderScary, on lines 503-515 and 603-630

Comment: didnt realize hitting enter commented. here is the pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/YNqnuZRY